creating a cell reference with a fixed column name and the line # from a value in a different cell
I have a workbook with data from multiple years in separate worksheets. On my summary worksheet I am using the following formula, plus multiple similar formulas, to analyze data: =AVERAGE('2024:2014'!A97)
I do this as new data is added but have to manually change the referenced row number in multiple formulas as new data is added to the latest worksheet. I would like to try and automate the process to update the referenced row number, column name stays the same.
I tried, =AVERAGE('2024:2014'!A(A5)), where A5 is the cell used to enter the value of the new row number I am looking at (enter 98 in A5 to get the formula(s) to read A98). I get a name error. I also tried to add the worksheet name (summary A5) and get name error.
Looking at other answers prior to submitting this question I found the recommendation to use indirect.
Tried =AVERAGE('2024:2014'!A(=INDIRECT("summary!"&"&$A$5))) and that did not work either, it would not accept my syntax.
Is there a possible solution to what I am trying to do?

Could you try something like =$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,lastrow), by defining lastrow with a suitable value? You may want to take a look at these: Define and use names in formulas - Microsoft Support, Dynamic named range with INDEX - Excel formula | Exceljet

INDIRECT() apparently cannot handle 3D references. If you have Office 365, try =AVERAGE(INDEX(HSTACK('2014:2024'!A:A),A5,0)).
